# Symfony2 web app on pagoda box: users unable to edit in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, pagoda-box

Very newbie to cloud sevices, I'm trying to develop a Symfony web site on Pagoda Box.

The database connection seem to work fine and no problem with the tunnel either. But when I test my online app, users seem to be able to "insert" but not to "update" or "delete" data. For example, a user can sign up but not edit his profil; an administrator can add things but not delete or edit them.

Are there some specific settings to do to configure users' right to write in database ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by saying "can't edit or delete"? Any errors?

Comment: No errors occurred.
For example, when a new user sign in and try to complete his profile, it just doesn't work. It seems to be blocked at the update action. But the app hosted on my local server works absolutely fine for this point. So I was wondering if there's a database access setting up on pagodabox?